# Dynamic predicate using a dictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, predicatebuilder

I'm using entity framework and I will recieve a dictionary of objects in the controller and that will help me to create a predicate on the repository.

I don't know how to create a dynamic predicate using the Dictionary Keys and Values. All Keys will be named as  entity properties, that means that on the followed example, the entity person have a property called Surname, and I want all Items with the surname Elliot.

```
Dictionary<string,Obect>()
```

With the followed data Key/Value:

```
 - "Surname","Elliot"
```

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to use reflection for this, that will be expensive.

Comment: Hi Dai ty, an example will be very usefull! I was trying to do it by reflection.. but the problem is that when I have the object I don't know how to create the lambda expresion -.-'

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835090/dynamically-generate-predicate-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you master the art of building dynamic queries life becomes easy.

**Method 1 :**

You can use dynamic linq expressions.

You have to use Dynamic Linq from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)

Once you have Dynamic Linq, you can write strings as queries and pass it as string in your where clause

For more information [visit](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

**Method 2:**

Follow this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq)

Comment: Ty Shadow your 2 link was useful for me ;)