# How to create a Predicate<T> dynamically on runtime

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees, predicate

I am trying to create a method in a base class capable of taking parameters and creating a `Predicate<T>` on the fly.

Here is the abstract class:

```
public abstract class Table<TResults>
    where TResults : class
{
    ...
    protected abstract List<TResults> Results { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And here is one class implementing `Table<TResults>`:

```
public class TrStudent
{
    ...

    public string Name => // some code
    ...

    public void Check()
    {
        // check implementation
    }
}

public class TableStudents : Table<TrStudent>
{
    ...
    protected override List<TrStudent> Results { get; set; }
    ...
    
    public void Check_Student(string studentName) => Results.Find(r => r.Name == studentName).Check();        
}
```

And here is another class implementing `Table<TResults>`:

```
public class TrAnswer
{
    ...
    public string Name => // some code
    public int Id => // some other code
    ...
    
    public void Report()
    {
        // report implementation
    }
}

public class TableAnswers<TrAnswer> : Table<TrAnswer>
{
    ...
    protected override List<TrAnswer> Results { get; set; }
    ...
    
    public void Report_Answer(string answerName, int answerId) => Results.Find(r => r.Name == answerName && r.Id == answerId).Report();
    ...
}
```

What I would like to do, if possible is update the `Table<TResults>` class to:

```
public abstract class Table<TResults>
    where TResults : class
{
    ...
    protected abstract List<TResults> Results { get; set; }
    ...
    protected abstract Predicate<T> Predicate { get; }
    protected T Find(parameters) => Results.Find(parameters, Predicate);
}
```

So I can update the derived classes to:

```
public class TableStudents : Table<TrStudent>
{
    ...        
    public void Check_Student(string studentName) => Find(studentName).Check();
}

public class TableAnswers<TrAnswer> : Table<TrAnswer>
{
    ...       
    public void Report_Answer(string answerName, int answerId) => Find(answerName, answerId).Report();
}
```

But I am not sure if this is possible as some lambdas take more parameters than others.

I have checked [Predicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-5.0), [Lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) and also [Expression class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-5.0) and I am almost sure it could be done, but I dont know where to start.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically generate predicate at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835090/dynamically-generate-predicate-at-runtime)

Comment: Hi Dave, well it helps but I am not sure how to adapt it to what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following not an option?

```cs
public abstract class Table<TResults> where TResults : class {
    // ...
    protected TResults Find(Predicate<TResults> predicate)
        => Results.Find(predicate);
}
```

```cs
public class TableStudents : Table<TrStudent> {
    // ...
    public void Check_Student(string studentName)
        => Find(r => r.Name == studentName).Check();
}
```

```cs
public class TableAnswers<TrAnswer> : Table<TrAnswer>
{
    // ...
    public void Report_Answer(string answerName, int answerId)
        => Find(r => r.Name == answerName && r.Id == answerId).Report();
}
```

I don't see the point in going through the hazzle to create a `Predicate<T>` at runtime.

---

Generally your solution looks a little bit too over-engineered, to be honest. What's the point of abstracting `List.Find()` when each subclass has to override the `List` of results anyway?

Those subclasses literally have everything they need to filter their results (i.e., the results itself and the predicate parameters), but still they must ask the abstract base class to filter for them?

---

If you need the predicate multiple times you could use a private function in each subclass that returns the `Predicate<TResults>` for the given parameters:

```cs
public class TableStudents : Table<TrStudent> {
    // ...

    public void Check_Student(string studentName)
        => Find(FilterBy(studentName)).Check();

    private static Predicate<TrStudent> FilterBy(string studentName)
        => r => r.Name == studentName;
}
```

```cs
public class TableAnswers<TrAnswer> : Table<TrAnswer>
{
    // ...
    public void Report_Answer(string answerName, int answerId)
        => Find(FilterBy(answerName, answerId)).Report();

    private static Predicate<TrAnswer> FilterBy(string answerName, int answerId)
        => r => r.Name == answerName && r.Id == answerId;
}
```

Don't feel compelled to extract those private `FilterBy()` functions into the base class only because they got identical names and work similarly. How a subclass filters is none of the base classes business. The subclass knows best how to filter its results and it might or might not use one or more private functions to create the `Predicate<T>`s it needs.

---

Note that `FilterBy()` is a function that returns a `Predicate<T>`. A `Predicate<T>` is a function object that returns a `bool` when you give it a `T` value.

It's similar to a regular function like `bool MyPredicate(T value) {...}`, only that you can store it in variables, pass it around, and even return it from other functions:

```cs
// create function object
var isAlphaNumeric = new Predicate<char>(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsDigit(c));

// call function object with some values
Debug.Assert(isAlphaNumeric('a') == true);
Debug.Assert(isAlphaNumeric('&') == false);
```

This more verbose version of `FilterBy()` might make the relation to `isAlphaNumeric` more clear:

```cs
private static Predicate<TrStudent> FilterBy(string studentName) {
    var hasName = new Predicate<TrStudent>(r => r.Name == studentName);
    return hasName;
}
```

The major difference between `isAlphaNumeric` and `hasName` is that `hasName` needs to *capture* the value of the `studentName` parameter by storing it inside the function object. Later, when the returned `hasName` function object is called by `List.Filter()` with one or more `TrStudent` objects, this value will be available for the name comparison.

---

By the way, a function returning a function (or taking other functions as parameters) are so called [*higher-order functions*](https://codinghelmet.com/articles/understanding-delegates-and-higher-order-functions-in-cs). C# took them from functional programming and they are very powerful. For instance, LINQ wouldn't be possible without them. But they can also replace some object-oriented design patterns like the strategy pattern, the template method pattern, the factory patterns, and even dependency injection.

Comment: Hi Good Night Nerd Pride, the problem is each Table<TResults> has a lot of methods that use the same Predicate<T> over and over, so I wanted to keep it DRY. When I started trying to resolve this problem I thought it would be much easier that it is turning up to be. However now I just wanted to learn how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, DRY is overrated. On the long run, duplication is much easier to maintain than complicated designs that try to extract every little duplication :)

Comment: if I could ask you, how does `private static Predicate<TrAnswer> FilterBy(string answerName, int answerId)
        => r => r.Name == answerName && r.Id == answerId;` have access to "r"? I don't understand the magic behind this part. Thank you!